# Binary Search ending in an infinite while loop

Tags: java, binary-search

I am trying to debug a bunch of code I have written for running a binary search. For some reason, it ending up in an infinite while loop and I am unable to figure out why. Could someone please help me with this.

```
public class BinarySearch {
        public static int doBinarySearch(int[] arr, int target){
            int start = 0;
            int end = arr.length - 1;
            int mid = start + (end - start)/2;
            while(start <= end){
                if(target == arr[mid])
                {
                    return mid;
                }
                else if(target < arr[mid])
                {
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
                else if(target > arr[mid])
                {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        
        public static void main(String[] args){
            
            int[] array = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
            int target = 3;
            int answer = doBinarySearch(array, target);
            System.out.println(answer);
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never update `mid` while you are looping.

Comment: plus it would be better for you to use your ide debug mode to trace those kind of error by tracing the execution process

Answer (score 2):

```
public class BinarySearch {
        public static int doBinarySearch(int[] arr, int target){
            int start = 0;
            int end = arr.length - 1;
           
            while(start <= end){
               int mid = start + (end - start)/2; // Mid should update inside loop
                if(target == arr[mid])
                {
                    return mid;
                }
                else if(target < arr[mid])
                {
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
                else if(target > arr[mid])
                {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        
        public static void main(String[] args){
            
            int[] array = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
            int target = 3;
            int answer = doBinarySearch(array, target);
            System.out.println(answer);
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

I think I got the Answer. The Middle should be calculated dynamically in the while loop. What was happening now is that that the start and end values were changing but the value of middle remained the same.

Comment: check my answer and mark accepted if it helped you

Comment: This should be removed.